# Crear columnas con máxima amplitud en la pagina

Tags: css, bootstrap

Estoy intentando crear dos columnas en la misma línea usando `bootstrap5` que ocupen toda la amplitud de la pantalla:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        1/2
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        2/2
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

El problema es que deja mucho margen en los laterales de la pagina, pero me gustaría que apenas tuviera márgenes en los laterales:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He probado a definir el `width` al 100% pero no hace nada:

```
.col {
  width: 100%;
}
```

¿Alguna idea de como solucionar esto?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El tema es que la `row` padre de ambas `col` está dentro de un `div` con clase "container", esta clase deja un margen a cada lado. Entonces todo lo que quede adentro jamás ocupará toda la pantalla.
Para resolver esto es suficiente con reemplazar la clase "container" por "container-fluid", esta última si ocupa el 100% del ancho.

Agregué la clase "border" a las `col` solo para que veas donde está cada una y hasta donde llega.

Quedaría así:

```
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col border">
              1/2
            </div>
            <div class="col border">
              2/2
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </body>
```

---

Para agregar un pequeño margen a los lados podrías ponerle un padding en el eje X al elemento padre, en este ejemplo es el `body`, pero podría ser cualquiero `div` o `section` por ejemplo.

Esto quedaría así:

```
<body class="px-2">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col border">
              1/2
            </div>
            <div class="col border">
              2/2
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </body>
```

Espero sirva para resolver lo que necesites hacer, quedo a las órdenes.

Comment: Perfecto, gracias!

Comment: Por nada, estoy a las órdenes.